# Obfuscation of variable names with whitespaces

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax

[image] 
My goal is not to use it in a real website, it's for knowledge and fun.

I want to write something like :

```
var  =3;
alert( );
```

(not with the space but with a specific unicode character)

Is it possible? And if not, is there something equivalent?

Comment: Basically, no. You may find this question interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7451524/707111

Comment: http://www.securelist.com/en/blog/208188101/Dangerous_whitespaces

Comment: @minitech yes but here http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers look in the comments.

Comment: @user1365010: Looking through them. One claimed to be whitespace, but  I saw a box...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Valid Characters for JavaScript Variable Names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)

Comment: @minitech yes but copy it in notepad and you will see

Comment: @user1365010: I still see a box. Anyway, if that answers your question already, why did you ask this question?

Comment: @minitech So strange, I don't really know why...

Comment: the basic premise of the question is you dont want variable names that can be deciphered by the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you cannot use any of the Unicode whitespace characters as "raw" names, you can do a bit of magic with `window` and bracket notation.

For example:

```
window["    "] = 1;
alert(window["    "]);
```

These are not "named" per se, as you cannot reference them without fiddling with properties of `window`, since JavaScript ignores spaces, but they will do the trick when it comes to obfuscation.

Of course, this could be extended arbitrarily to any object; `window` is not a requirement, but it is what came to mind since all global variables are properties of `window`. To that end, you could have something like:

```
var vars = {};
vars[" "] = 1;
vars["  "] = 2;
vars["   "] = 3;

alert(vars[" "] + vars["  "] + vars["   "]);
```

I think this is as close as you'll be able to get to having variables named with whitespaces. They're not *true* variables in the sense of the `var` keyword, but they are as close as you're likely to come.

Of course, you can use Unicode whitespace characters as properties too:

```
var vars = {};
vars[" "] = 1; // uses em quad, U+2001
alert(vars[" "]); // real variable, alerts 1
alert(vars[" "]); // fake variable, alerts undefined
```

In this case, I use U+2001 as a property. It looks mighty similar to the one after it, which is just a generic space in a string, but they are not the same as the alert suggests.

A potential "issue" with this, in terms of obfuscation, is that the strings are very clearly delimited thanks to proper monospace fonts and syntax highlighting, so I am not sure how useful raw spaces themselves will be. However, if you throw in some of the fancier Unicode spaces, your results may be better.