# Typescript doesn't like my variable name "⛄" and I can't suppress the error

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to write a server and I keeping typescript error that I cannot supress:

[image]

As you can see I already try to use ts-ignore but it does not supress the error, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
// @ts-ignore
const ⛄ = (fn) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    return fn(req, res, next).catch((err) => {
      return next(err);
    });
  };
};
```

EDIT:  Yes, this Unicode is valid Javascript variable name:
EDIT 2:  Apparently ⛄ is not valid, alrighty then.

Comment: It's not a TS error, it's a JS syntax error, so you can't ignore it.

Comment: Are you sure this is a valid js identifier? If so I'd report a bug. I remember a recent bug about strange characters in variables

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes, this is valid Javascript name, I am not getting a Javascript error, I am getting a Typescript error.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Yes, Unicode are valid Javascript name

Comment: @Bill I just tried it right now and got "SyntaxError: illegal character"

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Alright, I guess not all unicode are valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aren't ◎ܫ◎ and ☺ valid JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451524/why-arent-%dc%ab-and-valid-javascript-variable-names). They go into great detail there.

Comment: @MilanVelebit Good duplicate, didn't see that one before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JavaScript variable name validator](https://mothereff.in/js-variables) it's an invalid identifier:

[image]

If you still think it should be valid, then maybe a defect report is the next step.

Comment: I believe you, I will use that website

Answer (score 1):

"That’s an invalid identifier according to ECMAScript 6 / Unicode 8.0.0."

You are getting a javascript error, not a typescript one.

Also.. *I don't think naming variables with emojis is good coding practice.*

https://mothereff.in/js-variables#%E2%9B%84